# unable to run C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar create-project symfony/skeleton C:\Users\EMMANUEL\projet_symfony --no-interaction

Tags: symfony-2.1

j'ai créé un projet symfony et j'ai essayé d'afficher la première page mais elle ne s'affiche pas parceque l'url n'a pas été configuré ,pourquoi ma première page symfony ne s'affiche pas?Oubien comment configuré l'url afin de pourvoir afficher une page